# Django use a method a form in class based view

Tags: django, forms

So I am trying to run a form method in my form view.

I saw an example here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Here is my view:

```
class SignupView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'signup.html'
    form_class = cp_forms.SignupForm
    success_url = '/control-panel/login/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.generate_username()

        return super(SignupView, self).form_valid(form)
```

And in my form:

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
     first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
     last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
     birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))

    # Generate a custom username using the slug
    def generate_username(self):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        birthdate = self.cleaned_data['birthdate']

        member = Member.objects.filter(first_name=first_name).filter(last_name=last_name).filter(birthdate=birthdate)[0]

        return member.slug

    # Generate a random password for the user
    def generate_random_password(self):
        return BaseUserManager.make_random_password()
```

But it returns an error:

Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'SignupForm' object has no attribute 'generate_username'

Here is the output of print type(form), dir(form), form

http://gyazo.com/c29832894e9a3255d0d51ce2993af6d5

Check_member_exists, check_member_account_exists, check_member_allowed generate_random_password is custom methods I added...

Thanks,
Ara

Comment: Is that the actual indentation?

Comment: @limelights I fixed it. Sorry about that

Comment: And how do you import it? Do you perhaps have two different SignupForms?

Comment: @limelights I only have 1 SignupForms...

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko that method is not the print. I have other methods that is in the form but not the generate_username().... I am super confused...

Comment: I also added the rest of the functions to give you an idea. (The indent didnt show up correctly. But all of them are indtented to be in the SignupForm class.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko It's other custom methods I have... That's why I find it weird that some of my methods are showing up but not the generate_username...

Comment: I dont see that `generate_username` anywhere in the definition of your form

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko How is that possible? It's right before my generate_random_password method...

Comment: Either you dont have that method in your form or you cant properly use copy-paste. Any of these things are ridiculous.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I cleaned up the code so it's easier for you to read.

Comment: Are you running the Django test server? What happens if you restart it? It might not have refreshed after you added the `generate_username` method.

Comment: Need full error traceback